# Please point out how I have managed to create an infinite loop

Tags: python, function, loops

```
def split_and_join(line):
    x=line.split()
    n=0
    while n< len(x):
        if n%2==0:
            x.insert(n,"-")
            n+=1
        else:
            pass
    print("".join(x))
```

At what point have I made the error? I know I have managed to create an infinite `while` loop, but I don't want the complete solution just the point where I forgot a detail or something.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Step through your program with a debugger - it becomes pretty obvious why you're stuck in an infinite loop pretty quickly. After the first time you hit `n % 2 != 0`, you never do anything. Since you don't do anything, `n % 2` is never zero again, and `n` stays `< len(x)` forever

Comment: You have an `else:` where `n` is not modified. I suspect that you end up looping where the `else:` is always taken and so the `while` can never quit.

Comment: `else: pass` is never needed. Just leave out the `else:` block.

Comment: Can't you just use `"-".join(x)`?

Comment: @Barmar I wanted to try it out this way too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've forgotten to add the `n+=1` statement after your else block and because of that the value of n never changes and constantly stays 0. Which leads to an infinite loop.

I would also recommend a for loop here instead since you know the exact number of times that the loop should be iterated i.e len(x). It would avoid having to specify the increment.

Comment: Actually it gets stuck at 1, not 0.

Comment: This answer would be more help if you actually showed how to rewrite the code correctly.

Comment: @cards oh yes my bad, I didn't notice the increment in the if block, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @barmar yeah it gets stuck at 1. I would have rewritten the code but the user asked for just an explanation and also I'm scrolling through my phone so typing out code is a bit i
Of a hassle.